# how to use the bean function in clojure

Tags: clojure

I don't really understand how the `bean` function works when I am using it on beans. This code here throws an exception:

```
(import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory)
(def runtime (bean (ManagementFactory/getRuntimeMXBean))
(:name runtime)


;; =>
Class clojure.core$bean$fn__5177$fn__5178 can not access a member of class sun.management.RuntimeImpl with modifiers "public"
  [Thrown class java.lang.IllegalAccessException]
```

but the class does have a method called `getName()`. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/RuntimeMXBean.html

Comment: BTW - https://github.com/clojure/java.jmx

Comment: I wrote this wrapper for improved system analytics https://github.com/zcaudate/sigmund

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have missed it, it's right there.

> getName() Returns the name representing the runn
>   (import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory)
>   (def runtime (bean (ManagementFactory/getRuntimeMXBean))
>   (:name runtime)

;; =>
Class clojure.core$bean$fn_*5177$fn*_5178 can not access a member of class sun.management.RuntimeImpl with modifiers "public"
  [Thrown class java.lang.IllegalAccessException]

but the class does have a method called getName(). http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/RuntimeMXBean.html

ing Java virtual machine.

Edit1:

This issue is very similar to one [here](http://markmail.org/message/cxyynkw5mvzlloxl#query%3a+page:1+mid%3acxyynkw5mvzlloxl+state%3aresults) and response to it is [here](http://markmail.org/message/cxyynkw5mvzlloxl#query%3a+page:1+mid%3aln4ksrdwuhmbpdwp+state%3aresults).

Class `RuntimeImpl` returned by `ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean` is only package visible but it implements public visible interface `RuntimeMXBean`. So what happens is that function `bean` tries to call a method on the class `RuntimImpl` but it can't as class is only package visible. I think if it tried to call `getMethod` on interface `RuntimeMXBean` it would have worked.

---

Yeap this works:

```
(def mx-bean (ManagementFactory/getRuntimeMXBean))
(def interface-method 
  (.getMethod RuntimeMXBean "getName" (into-array java.lang.Class [])))
(.invoke interface-method mx-bean (into-array []))
```

I'm not sure if it's a bug or feature. I would recommend asking on Clojure mailing list.

Comment: thats my point... the bean throws an exception when i try to access it using clojure's implementation

Comment: thanks for that! there are work arounds for my problem but it is quite interesting to figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is captured by a bug right here: http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-978?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel

Upvote it!

You can roll-your-own bean function using the available patch.